# How to upload a file with new version usign SHAREOINT REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, update, sprequest

I wrote some code to update a file in My SharePoint library using SharePoint-rest-Api and [sp-request](https://github.com/s-KaiNet/sp-request).
I tried to replicate [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn450841.aspx#CodeSnippetContainerCode_f58a6af4-5ae1-4575-9e29-cb3b516c91b4) example from msdn pages, and it works.

```
return spr.post('http://vm2008sharepo/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(\'/Documents/MyDoc.docx\')/$value', {
                body: file,
                json: false,
                headers: {
                    'X-RequestDigest': digest,
                    'X-HTTP-Method': 'PUT',
                    'IF-MATCH': '*',

                }
            });
```

the problem is that when it updates a file the version does not change.
So I tried these adding parameters in the post, but no luck :

`UIVersionLabel: '0.2',`

`UIVersion: 2,`
 I also tried to use **POST**, **MERGE** and **PATCH** instead of **PUT** but all I got is exceptions. 
I suspect that this web service does not **undate** the file (since it uses PUT) but changes it's content, so the version does not change.
Is it possible to change the version when updating or is there an other web service to use in order to do so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally if versioning enabled, you need to do the following:

1. Check out
2. Upload
3. Check in

Check out:

```
sprequest.post("https://my_sharepoint/sites/dev/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(@FileUrl)/CheckOut()?@FileUrl='" + encodeURIComponent(fileServerRelativeUrl) + "'", {
    headers: {
      'X-RequestDigest': digest
    }
 });
```

Upload:

```
sprequest.post('https://my_sharepoint/sites/dev/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(@FolderName)/Files/add(url=@FileName,overwrite=true)' +
            ("?@FolderName='" + encodeURIComponent(folder) + "'&@FileName='" + encodeURIComponent(fileName) + "'"), {
    headers: {
        'X-RequestDigest': digest
    },
    body: fileContent,
    json: false
});
```

Check in:

```
sprequest.post('https://my_sharepoint/sites/dev/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(@FileUrl)/CheckIn(comment=@Comment,checkintype=@Type)' +
            ("?@FileUrl='" + encodeURIComponent(fileServerRelativeUrl) + "'&@Comment='" + (checkinMessage) + "'") +
            ("&@Type='" + checkinType + "'"), {
    headers: {
        'X-RequestDigest': digest
    }
});
```

CheckInType is a number:

- MinorCheckIn: 0
- MajorCheckIn: 1
- OverwriteCheckIn: 2

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Kai that was it. One thing though the execution of these functions has to be sequential. I had to force them using promises.

Comment: Right, absolutely true

Answer (score 1):

Make your request as below:

```
http://vm2008sharepo/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/Documents/MyDoc.docx')/CheckIn(comment='Comment', checkintype=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of "OverwriteCheckIn: 2" there is no new version created.

MinorCheckIn: 0  -> version 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, ...

MajorCheckIn: 1  -> version 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ...

OverwriteCheckIn: 2 -> version 1.0, 1.0, 1,0 ...