# Uploading files from node/Express.js server to sharepoint

Tags: javascript, development, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to send a file to a SharePoint folder using the sp-request module.
I can upload a .txt file and it opens correctly.
But when uploading .docx files, the file becomes corrupted.

My collection of .docx files resides in a node server.
I've tried sending the file buffer obtained from `fs.readFile(filename)`, as well as the encoded content obtained from `fs.readFile(filename, "utf8")`.

Either way, the file is uploaded and arrives at the destination folder, but it cannot be opened. The error is: "This file can't be opened for editing", and it won't open in the desktop as well.

Here's my controller function in express, where `spr` is sp-request:

```
async function uploadFile(req, res, next) {
  
  try {
    const filename = "filename.docx"
    const file = await fs.readFile(filename, "utf8");
    const url = siteURL + `_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('FolderName')/Files/add(url='${filename}',overwrite=true)`;

    const digest = await spr.requestDigest(siteURL);

    const result = await spr.post(url, {
      headers: {
        'X-RequestDigest': digest,
      },
      body: file,
      json: false,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `accept` header and a `content-length` header ([ref](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery)). I'd guess that's your problem.

But I'd suggest using [spsave](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spsave) instead of sp-request. It was written by the same person and uses sp-request under the hood. `spsave` will handle all the document library idiosyncrasies for you.

Comment: As per [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/200565/how-to-upload-a-file-with-new-version-usign-shareoint-rest-api) I don't think I need extra headers. But, I did try your suggestion of adding them manually. No success.

Comment: I ended up using spsave as recommended. However, I cannot accept the above answer as it did not solve/explained the issue I was facing. I DO recommend that people use spsave for saving time.

Answer (score 0):

There is a NodeJS-SharePoint example project for what you are trying to achieve: [github.com/drass/node-sharepoint-file-sharing](https://github.com/drass/node-sharepoint-file-sharing)

It uses `sppull` and `spsave`, I recommend trying out these modules instead of sp-request.